# What to do when a wrong answer is posted incorrectly saying the accepted answer is wrong

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm pretty sure that my answer to a question is correct, with 77 upvotes. Have retested just now.

Author of a new answer says the accepted answer is wrong, but they won't respond to comments asking to show their justification or to amend their answer. I suspect they have used an online "regex tester" instead of running the java code specified in the question.

I feel that in this case, since the answer specifically says another answer is incorrect (when it isn't) that a downvote and a comment is not enough. What action should I take?

Link:

[How to check if a string contains only digits in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111420/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-only-digits-in-java/30321751#30321751)

Comment: I think a downvote and a comment is satisfactory. I understand you feel challenged, but when it comes to those looking for an answer, your accepted, high-scoring answer will be enough.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like OP was last online 2 days ago, so be patient. They may not sign on every day.

Comment: @Trobbins Okay, thanks. I'll let the downvoting mechanism take it's course, even if it may cause some confused readers to use a little more time to compile and test both answers.

Comment: Just get three 20k+ (or whatever it is) to delete. I have.

Comment: Well, as a side effect - posting on meta is a good way to get a flood of downvotes (4 in this case). Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Hah, you're wrong and he's right.  Your regex only tests that the string contains a digit whereas the question asks for a regex that determines if the string "contains **only digits**".  You might want to clarify your answer if you have a reason why this isn't correct.

Comment: @Will I'm sorry, did you miss the `+` in the regular expression in my answer? Did you test the code?

Comment: lol, I don't have to test your code, I can read regular expressions.  Your regex will match one or more digits in a row.  You tell me, would it not find a match in the following string -- "abc123"?  It would match "123" certainly.  [meh, snip this assertion; I don't know enough about java to make this call]  I can tell you for a fact that your regex, in and of itself, can falsely match a negative case.  The answer which you complain about correctly starts and ends the regex with the line start and line ending anchors that you fail to have.

Comment: @Will you've made the same incorrect presumption as the answer I raised issue about. Please read the question again, it states the usage of the regular expression, via the `matches(...)` method, which if you are unfamiliar with java matches a complete string (e.g. `123` but not `abc123`). And generally speaking since the question specifies code, I think you really should make the effort to test the code before calling out an answer as wrong. I note specifically that the question says `in Java`, not `in regular expressions`.

Comment: Ya, just ideone'd it.  `matches` method forces a match against the entire string, even if the regex doesn't specify it.  The last line of your above comment doesn't make sense, but I cede the point.

Comment: @Will no worries :) glad we resolved it today in the actual answers. Much clearer now that the answer at issue has dropped negative.

Comment: I'm confused. The accepted answer includes "\\d+" which is what's being suggested in the new answer. The addition of "$" in the new answer is superficial, as the original question doesn't mention if it should match multiline or not.

Comment: Both answers are wrong. The question asks to match strings containing only digits. Your answer fails to match the empty string, which (vacuously) contains only digits.

Comment: You could have headed off the confusion by pointing out that `matches` implicitly anchors to the start and end of the string — even if not needed by the OP, it would help others passing by and trying to learn.

Comment: @dfeuer Are you sure? Why are so many people jumping to conclusions on this without obviously testing the code. I have just retested and my answer does not match an empty string. Regex `\\d*` would have done so, but `\\d+` does not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, thanks, I'll add an explanation about how `matches` works, and a comment that online "regex checkers" might operate differentlly.

Comment: @vikingsteve, as I said.

Comment: @vikingsteve, since the empty string contains only numbers, a correct regex will match it.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm sure that this is not the spirit of the question. Most people/programmers I know would take "Contains only X" to mean "Contains some X, and nothing else" rather than "Doesn't contain anything that isn't X".

Comment: @Will "I don't have to test your code, I can read regular expressions." Bwahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: Was the new answer deleted? I don't see it.

Comment: Good job @vikingsteve, you got the answer deleted and a ton of upvotes! Yay! Thanks for bringing it to everyone's attention!

Comment: @KyleStrand yep, the answer is now deleted. If you have 5000 rep I think you can see deleted answers.

Comment: @KyleStrand I normally don't debase myself to touch Java, but OP seemed insistent, so I did.  Had to shower in lava afterwards, tho.

Comment: @Will "Modraters are just monkeys who has guns in there hands" - your profile, lol.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think a comment and a downvote is sufficient in this case. Simply running the code in this case will tell anyone who really wants to know which answer is correct. (Unlike, say, a question about a security vulnerability, where people really can be fooled by answers that *look* correct, but aren't.)

Comment: Okay, the thing however is that the other answer isn't incorrect - it also works for a positive test case. But from how it is written, people who read and use that answer may then incorrectly infer that my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @vikingsteve If running the code doesn't tell them which answer is correct (or that both are), then the comments can do that. There's really nothing else to do, unless you want to edit your own answer with test cases proving it works.

Comment: @vikingsteve Worth noting is that it's unlikely anyone who would assume your answer is incorrect just from that claim probably won't be thorough enough to read past the first two highly upvoted answers, anyway. Or probably wouldn't have been willing to read your entire answer to begin with (since it's a little long). You can't make everyone happy. Just focus on providing high quality content and being humble enough to accept criticism and correction. Don't worry about every last passerby. You'll drive yourself nuts that way. ;)

Comment: If the answer simply states that your own answer is incorrect, but it then goes on to provide its own answer, I'd simply edit it to remove the 'fluff'.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to post a comment. So I will just add an answer here.

I looked through all comments (and tested the actual use case) and looks like I was wrong that   @vikingsteve answer is incorrect.

Do not have any objections about deletion of my answer.

Comment: No worries. I've had to delete my own answer plenty of times when I misread the question :) The bonus is you get the rep back if it had negative downvotes.

Comment: I appreciate you as a new user come to Meta and constructively contribute to the discussion. +1

Answer (score 4):

I think the accepted answer here is incorrect and will fool everyone who will come here for the answer.

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant.

Answer (score -3):

This conflict comes from misunderstanding how the pattern with be used to check the string. If `\d+` or `[0-9]+` is used with [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), it will, indeed, match any substring, regardless of the characters around. In this case we need to add the boundary markers, `^` and `$`.

However the correct way to use these patterns is by calling [matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) instead. Then it would work, and the answer would be correct.

Hence the correct pattern string belongs from the used Java code.

Such problems come from the lack of attention when reading the others question, answer or comment, also the lack of the necessary respect. We should discuss the disagreements quietly and come to the consensus, rather than calling all hell on the opponents head.

In this particular case it is not possible to tell how the pattern string would be used. The Java code in the question is not correct enough to understand this. Hence the correct answer should also include the fragment of Java code, using the proposed pattern.